# ng2-dragula style original element when copying

Tags: angular, dragula, ng2-dragula

We're using the `copy: true` setting with `ng2-dragula`:

```
constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
    dragulaService.setOptions('group-body-bag', {
        copy: true,
        copySortSource: true
    });
}
```

Now we want to fade out the original element (the one that is still sitting in the list while we are dragging) with something like `opacity: 0.3`. How can we do that? Using

```
dragulaService.cloned.subscribe((value) => {
    if (value && value.length && value.length === 4 && value[3] === 'copy') {
        this.onDragCopy(value[1]);
    }
});
```

we can find the original element and we could apply a transparancy to it, bit this seems awfully wrong: The draggable elements (naturally) come from a data-array, is there a way to find the dragged element's index so we can do something like

```
dragulaService.cloned.subscribe((index) => {
    this.draggedElement = index;
});
```

and

```
<li *ngFor="let article of articles; let i = index"
  [class.original-dragged-element]="draggedElement === i">
```

(I know, this is bad already, I should match article).

Comment: This is not "dragular" realted, please correct tag to "dragula", thanks ;)

Comment: @Luckylooke I have corrected the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided that the Angula way is to manipulate data and have a template render the classes.